# SQL select the records that have the same name but more than one type of te_source

Tags: sql

[image]

this is my table and I would like to show the records that have the same name but more than one type of te_source
and this will be result only

[image]

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have it (it just have to check that there are rows with the same name but a different source) :

```
SELECT * 
FROM MY_TABLE 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM MY_TABLE as ALTERNATE_SOURCE 
              WHERE MY_TABLE.tep_first_name = ALTERNATE_SOURCE.tep_first_name and 
                    MY_TABLE.tep_last_name = ALTERNATE_SOURCE.tep_last_name and
                    MY_TABLE.te_source <> ALTERNATE_SOURCE.te_source)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM  
    MyTable
WHERE 
    tep_PK IN
    (
        SELECT 
            tep_PK
        FROM 
            MyTable
        GROUP BY 
            tep_PK
        HAVING 
            COUNT(*) > 1
    )
```

Comment: No, this SQL will also return, for example, DIONNEL WIGGINS, because it has three rows. But all three rows share the same te_source. This is not the result he asked for, he must only get WILLIAMS KIMBERLY.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query .

```
   SELECT *
   FROM YourTable a
   JOIN (  SELECT tep_lastname,tep_FirstName
            FROM YourTable
                    GROUP BY tep_lastname,tep_FirstName
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT te_source)>1)b
    ON  a.tep_lastname=b.tep_lastname AND a.tep_FirstName=b.tep_FirstName
```

Comment: this really works but dont forget group by before the having

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Yup.. I answered through my phone.. So I missed.. :) any way mark as right answer if it helped you..